# Is it a correct way to use auto-implemented properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I want to assign some default value to a property or want to replace some character like given below. Is it a correct syntax or should i do this by creating a variable.

```
 public string Login_Name 
        { 
          get 
            { return this.Login_Name; } 
          set { this.Login_Name = value.Replace("'", "''"); } 
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean an auto implemented property?

Comment: why do you allow single quotes on log-in name? i'd rather filter all special characters through Regex instead of just replacing a single quote to a double single quote.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By accessing `Login_Name` the `get` will return `Login_Name` again leaving you with an infinite loop (`StackOverflowException`).

You should use properties to get and set private members:

```
public string Login_Name
{
   get
   {
      return _login_Name;
   }
   set
   {
      _login_Name = value;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_login_Name))
      {
         _login_Name = _login_Name.Replace("'", "''");
      }
   }
}
private string _login_Name;
```

If you meant to use an [auto-implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) property, it would look like this:

```
public string Login_Name {get;set;}
```

But auto-implemented properties cannot have any additional logic applied to their gets or sets.

Answer (score 4):

That won't work; you'd effectively be creating an infinite loop.

Use a separate private field instead:

```
private string m_loginName;

public string Login_Name 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return m_loginName; 
    } 
    set 
    {
       m_loginName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.Replace("'", "''") : value;
    } 
}
```

Comment: indeed -- i was copying the OP's code. :-)  I have updated it, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you have written is not an auto-implemented property. An [auto-implemented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) property would look like this:

```
 public string Login_Name { get; set; }
```

Here is a quote from MSDN, emphasis mine:

> In C# 3.0 and later, auto-implemented properties make property-declaration more concise **when no additional logic is required in the property accessors**.

When you have extra logic like in your example you cannot use an auto-implemented property. You can use an ordinary [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) and declare the backing field yourself.

```
 private string loginName;

 public string LoginName 
 { 
      get
      {
          return loginName;
      } 

      set
      {
          loginName = (value == null) ? null : value.Replace("'", "''");
      } 
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this.

```
private string _Login_Name = "Some Default";

public string Login_Name 
{ 
  get { return _Login_Name; } 
  set 
  {  
      _Login_Name = value.Replace("'", "''");  //might want to check for null first
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set a variable, otherwise you'll end up with infinite recursion and a Stack Overflow. With what you have, your setter is calling itself with:

```
this.Login_Name = ...
```

This is in the same way that your getter is calling itself with:

```
return this.Login_Name;
```

Answer (score -1):

It's correct. The only problem in the snippet that you provided is the recursive call of setter method of the property.

```
set { this.Login_Name = value.Replace("'", "''"); }
```

you should set value to some private field rather than recursively to the property itself, for example:

```
set { loginName = value.Replace("'", "''"); }
```

Comment: It is not: 1st it is not an auto-implemented property and 2nd this will crash if value is null